# Spark doesn't show all Hive databases

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

If I list all the databases in Hive, I get the following result (I have 2 tables default ans sbm):

[image]

But if I try to do the same thing in spark I get this

[image]

It doesn't show the database SBM.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connected to that hive metastore? Did you specify somewhere the metastore details (i.e. hive-site.xml in spark-conf directory) ? Seems like you are connected to the local merastore.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need copy your hive-site.xml to spark/conf directory.

If you use ubuntu and defined the environmental variables use the next command:

cp $HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml $SPARK_HOME/conf